# Should I touch nothing when I run production service server?

Tags: security, update, patch-management

I am going to run my first public game service server later. And many people advise not to touch anything if it's running well. I agree with them.

But one thing I am curious is, the security updates. Game servers are usually being attacked by many people - bad users. I don't know what kind of attacks will come, and actually all what I know are just heard from other people, not actually I've experienced.

I think I have to install latest security update at least. But too many people are saying *never though anything*.

What should I do for security patches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should never touch anything in production *unless there's a good reason to do so*. Security updates are a very good reason. And as Iain mentions, testing beforehand helps you to ensure that nothing is likely to go wrong when you apply the updates to your production system.

Answer (score 6):

I'll add to Michael's statement of the bleedin obvious with one of my own

You should never touch anything in production *unless there's a good reason to do so and you have tested it beforehand*.